# Creating new attribute field in Catalog->Manage Categories->Display Settings

Tags: attributes, dropdown-attribute

Im trying to add attribute field in the Display settings in Manage Categories. I found this tutorial on the web http://www.marketingadept.com/blog/magento-developers-add-a-custom-field-to-the-category-admin-page/

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
<CmsBlock>

<version>0.0.1</version>
</CmsBlock>
</modules>
<global>
<resources>
<cmsblock_setup>
<setup>
<module>CmsBlock</module>
<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
<connection>
<use>core_setup</use>
</connection>
</setup>
</cmsblock_setup>
<cms_block_setup_write>
<connection>
<use>core_write</use>
</connection>
</cms_block_setup_write>
<cms_block_setup_read>
<connection>
<use>core_read</use>
</connection>
</cms_block_setup_read>
</resources>
</global>
</config>
```

**mysql4-install-0.0.1.php**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');


$attributeSetId   = $installer->getAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

$attributeGroupId = $installer->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId,5);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cms_block',  array(
    'type'     => 'varchar', /* Type - see eav_entity_* for the different types */
    'label'    => 'CMS Block', /* Your label */
    'input'    => 'select', /* This refers to the type of form field should display*/
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => TRUE,
    'required'          => FALSE,
    'user_defined'      => FALSE,
    'option'           => array('values'=> array('Option 1','Option 2'))
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'cms_block',
    '52' 
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

the installer script does run as I checked it in the **core_resources** table but the field does not display on the Display Settings Tab. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group is missing in your attribute setup it should be like this

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cms_block',  array(
    'type'     => 'varchar', /* Type - see eav_entity_* for the different types */
    'label'    => 'CMS Block', /* Your label */
    'input'    => 'select', /* This refers to the type of form field should display*/
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => TRUE,
    'required'          => FALSE,
    'user_defined'      => FALSE,
    'option'           => array('values'=> array('Option 1','Option 2')),
    'group'            => 'Display Settings',    
));
```

Comment: I have added it sir but still it does not appear in the Display Settings tab.

Comment: @janers2014 sorry i misunderstood here your code seems correct

Comment: your attribute is available under general tab ?

Comment: the attribute should be available at the Display Settings tab. I even tried it in the general tab but it does not display also.

Comment: that might be your attribute is not setup in DB.check table  eav_attribute  and search attribute_code cms_block

Comment: if attribute is not available remove entry of cmsblock_setup from core_resource table and reload magento page,it will install your attribute

Comment: I already did it  but still its not creating the attribute. do I need to create the attribute manually?